# Performance of order of imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Common standards are to order imports alphabetically, and linters will generally order them for us.

Other than just being easier to read? Does the order of imports have any impact on performance? Perhaps on larger projects, will it slow down any if the imports are sorted randomly?

Upon googling, I found [this Java-specific S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500256/does-import-statements-sequence-have-any-effect/3500280#3500280), proclaiming that imports don't matter after compile-time. However, since JavaScript is interpreted rather than compiled, how much of a difference will the import order make?

Comment: Why do you think it would make any difference?

Comment: @Blackhole Mostly just curious, I don't have much of a reason to believe it makes a difference other than that someone said to me that it does.

Comment: Which module system are you using? Webpack? System.js? Node?

Comment: @meriton I'd primarily be interested in Node